# Getting error in firebug with ddslick

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, firebug

I am getting the following error when using the [ddslick](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Scripts/jquery.ddslick.min.js) jquery plugin. Tried too much to fix it, but I cant find out whats the error. Can somebody help me?

Error

```
 c.find(".dd-select").on is not a function
```

code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#media_idselect').ddslick({
        selectText: "Select the media",
    });

}); 
</script>
<select id="demo-htmlselect">
    <option value="0" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
        data-description="Description with Facebook">Facebook</option>
    <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
        data-description="Description with Twitter">Twitter</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
        data-description="Description with LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option>
    <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
        data-description="Description with Foursquare">Foursquare</option>
</select>
```

jQuery library Version :jquery-1.6.4.min.js

jQuery UI Version : jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of jQuery you are using? use the jquery 1.7.2 as recommended and there is an error in your code. You are using ddscick() on "#media_idselect", where the ID of the select tag is #demo-htmlselect#